# SSD In iMac G4 not recognized

Tags: imac, ssd, powerpc, sata

I recently bought an SSD and an IDE to SATA adapter. I've installed these into my iMac G4 (it's the 20" 1.25GHz model) neither the Leopard installer or Disk Utility will recognize it.

The SSD is 
http://www.memoryexpress.com/Products/MX49961

And the adapter is http://www.memoryexpress.com/Products/MX30129

I've heard that some iMacs will only work with SATA II, but I've also heard that this doesn't matter if using an adapter.

Just wondering where I should start troubleshooting. Is there anything obvious wrong with these two pieces of hardware?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you properly master/slave the adapter?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your SSD is working by connecting it to different computer through SATA or SATA to USB adapter.
2. Make sure your PATA adapter is working by connecting it to different computer. Also try different drive with it.
3. Try to buy another adapter with another chip, *prefer unidirectional one*.

There a whole lot of incompatibilities with them
[This one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-PATA-IDE-to-SATA-Card-Adapter-Converter-for-3-5-HDD-DVD-SPC-2599-/350915901429?pt=US_Drive_Cables_dapters&hash=item51b437b7f5) for example is working fine in my FW IDE enclosure with TI chip and not in the FW enclosure with some different chip. *Go figure!*

Answer (score 0):

1. Is everything plugged in securely? Double/triple check it.
2. Does the drive + adapter work in another computer? I'd recommend troubleshooting with another Mac AND a Windows machine if you can. If the drive shows up in Windows but not your Mac, then I'd expect it's a formatting issue.

I don't know of any limitation that would suggest that the parts are incompatible, so I expect that you'll find your answer while trying suggestion #2. If it doesn't work in any other computer, you probably have a bad adapter or SSD. If it works in Windows and not Mac, probably a formatting issue. If it works in another Mac, try reformatting/repartitioning it on that and try again on your G4.

If that still fails, then I can only assume there's some hardware limitation of your G4 that won't recognize the SSD through the adapter. I don't think that'd be it, though...